# Looking to filter nested structure based on predefined array of strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Schema:

```
root
 |-- group: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

`tags` will look something like this:

```
1 ["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"]
2 []
3 ["Cat"]
4 ["Zebra"]
```

I want to filter my entire data frame if one of `["Cat", "Dog"]` shows up. After this rule is applied the following rows would be left:

```
1 ["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"]
3 ["Cat"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Where `df` is your dataframe with your data

```scala
df.filter("arrays_overlap(tags,array('Cat','Dog'))")
```

You may use the [array_overlap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_overlap) to filter your tags